# Checking if a string is a valid URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Scenario:**

`a = 'some%20string';`

*URI(a) # throws*

```
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?)
```

How do I check if a string is a valid URI before passing it to URI?

Comment: `URI('some%20string')` gives me `#<URI::Generic:0x007ffe848b8ac8 URL:some%20string>`

Comment: maybe my answer on this question could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234613/validate-presence-of-url-in-html-text/16238176#16238176 - it works with general URI.extract.. so you can extract the URI out of your string and pass it..

Comment: I'd go with this answer, as `Addressable::URI` has the best URI-handling I've experienced so far: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11958835/215168

Answer (score 2):

You can still use the original method asked, just wrap it in some sort of error handling:

```
require 'uri'

u = nil
begin
  u = URI('hi`there')
rescue URI::InvalidURIError => e
  puts "error: #{e}"  #handle error
end

p u if u  #do something if successful
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a method, but looking at the [source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/uri/common.rb#L120) for `URI`, it performs a simple check:

```
case uri
when ''
  # null uri
when @regexp[:ABS_URI]
  # ...
when @regexp[:REL_URI]
  # ...
else
  raise InvalidURIError, "bad URI(is not URI?): #{uri}"
end
```

`URI()` uses the default parser, so something like this should work:

```
if URI::DEFAULT_PARSER.regexp[:ABS_URI] =~ a || URI::DEFAULT_PARSER.regexp[:REL_URI] =~ a
  # valid
end
```